# How to get the additional CA dll from a Wix Custom Action build into a nuget package?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, nuget-package, custom-action, wix4

I have a Wix Custom Action DLL that is used in multiple installer projects. I'd like to deploy this DLL to our nuget repository so it is easier to share.  However, the `dotnet pack` command doesn't put the correct DLL in the package.  The project builds 2 DLLs.  `WixInstallTools.dll` and `WixInstallTools.CA.dll`.  I'm not actually sure if installer projects need both DLLs or not, but they certainly need `WixInstallTools.CA.dll`.  How do I get this CA DLL into the nuget package.  I'm using Wix4 in a Visual Studio 2022 environment. The following is my project file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)</OutputPath>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <Authors>author</Authors>
    <Company>company</Company>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>true</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>false</IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
    
    <PackageId>WixInstallTools</PackageId>
    <PackageDescription>Wix Custom Action Library</PackageDescription>
    <PackageTags>WixInstallTools;Wix Install Tools;Wix;Install;Tools</PackageTags>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/company/nuget</RepositoryUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="CustomAction.config" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Dtf.CustomAction" Version="4.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Dtf.WindowsInstaller" Version="4.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
    <Reference Include="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up brute forcing this solution for myself.  I decided to hand craft a .nuspec file and fed that into nuget.  There might be more elegant "supported" ways of doing this, but I just got tired of fighting with it.  Here is my .nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>WixInstallTools</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <authors>author</authors>
    <tags>WixInstallTools Wix Install Native</tags>
    <description>install library</description>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
     <file src="WixInstallTools.CA.dll" target="runtimes/win-x64/native"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

The .CA.dll (native PE) contains the .DLL (.NET Framework Assembly).  This would be considered a native runtime dependency.

If it's possible... this page will explain how.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/native-files-in-net-packages

Now what you could also do is turn your custom actions into a full blown WiX extension.  Those get distributed as managed DLLs and are build time references for the compiler. Take a look at the repos for extensions such as IIS, Util and others.